# How to edit an array of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Lets say I have a react state variable which is an array of *user* objects. The user object has 2 keys which are important to us: *id* and *name*. I have to change the *name* of 2 users in that list. The code for this is below

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const users = await response.json();
    setUsers(users);
  }, [])
  
  const edit1 = (id) => {
    const newUsers = users.map(user => {
      if(user.id === id) {
        user.name = 'John Doe';
      } 
      return user;
    });    
    setUsers(newUsers);
  }
  
  const edit2 = (id) => {
    const newUsers = users.map(user => ({
      ...user,
      name: user.id === id ? 'Jane Doe' : user.name
    }));
    setUsers(newUsers);
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => edit1(2)}>Edit-1</button>
      <button onClick={() => edit2(5)}>Edit-2</button>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (<li key={user.key}>{user.name}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

Which approach is better? Between *edit1* and *edit2* which approach is better, since they both get the job done? Or is there another way to do this?

The problem is fairly straight forward. In *edit1*, new objects are not created, but a new array is created. Since React only checks to see if the reference to the array object has changed, which it has, it then goes on to rerender. In *edit2*, new objects are also created along with a new array. This causes a rerender as well. I'm confused as to which approach is better.

Comment: You could use immer to grab a deep-copy.

Comment: I guess I could just as well use a structuredClone() to create a deep copy

Answer (score 2):

You should use the function-version of "setState". This grabs the current state so that you can set it without depending on the state itself. If you had this inside of      `useEffect`, you could infinitely loop.

```js
setUsers((existingUsers) =>
  existingUsers.map((user) => ({
    ...user,
    name: user.id === id ? "John Doe" : user.name // Apply change within spread
  }))
);
```

If you would like to avoid spreading; because this can become problematic with deeply-nested structures, you could use an immutable library such as [`Immer`](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce/). Furthermore, Immer is used by Redux.

```js
setUsers(
  produce((draftUsers) => {
    draftUsers.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        user.name = "Jane Doe"; // Directly mutate the draft state
      }
    });
  })
);
```

Immer also has a `useImmer` hook that you can use to mutate your state. This removes the need to place the `produce` call in the middle of your state update.

For more info see: https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer

```js
const [users, updateUsers] = useImmer([]); // use-immer hook

const edit3 = (id) => {
  updateUsers((draftUsers) => {
    draftUsers.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        user.name = "Jane Doe";
      }
    });
  });
};
```

### Working example

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-immer-setstate-p8nplz?file=/src/App.jsx) for a live version.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import produce from "immer";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      const users = await response.json();
      setUsers(users);
    })();
  }, []);

  // Spread existing
  const edit1 = (id) => {
    setUsers((existingUsers) =>
      existingUsers.map((user) => ({
        ...user,
        name: user.id === id ? "John Doe" : user.name
      }))
    );
  };

  // Using Immer
  const edit2 = (id) => {
    setUsers(
      produce((draftUsers) => {
        draftUsers.forEach((user) => {
          if (user.id === id) {
            user.name = "Jane Doe";
          }
        });
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => edit1(2)}>Edit-1</button>
      <button onClick={() => edit2(5)}>Edit-2</button>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.key}>{user.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using edit2 you create a new array and new elements inside. But with edit1 even if you have a new array, the objects inside still have the refference to the old objects. So I suggest edit2.

Comment: Does this not create a problem when the array is too long or there are many keys in each object? Doesn't copying an object become a performance issue?

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right. Then you can just spread the object that you're editing. And let the others as they are.